# Direct connection Ethernet

Tags: ssh, ethernet, remote

I want to program my raspberry pi by connecting it directly to my laptop via Ethernet cable (ssh Xming), I use a 3G dongle to connect my laptop to internet, when I unplug the dongle there will be no connection and ip address will not be available. So should I set a static ip  for my laptop also?  What ip address, subnetmask and default gateway should I give my laptop and raspberry pi to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Static IP on ethernet interface both on Pi and Laptop. Use a subet which is different than that of 3G dongle.

---

Edit: Seems that this is not a specific raspberry pi question, but rather basic networking..

Comment: It is off topic but if we get quick reasonable solutions that's fine.  The primary goal of closing of off-topic questions like this is to help the OP find appropriate help, but if s/he's happy with this great.